# Generate xyz coordinates of a tube made of multiple rings

Tags: python, csv, numpy

In this code, I generate the coordinates of a tube made of multiple rings. Finally, I write those x,y,z coordinates in a .csv file. I want to simplify this code (maybe using a for loop?).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bLength=1.6
numPoints=10
radius = bLength*numPoints / (2 * np.pi)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,numPoints,endpoint=False)
dtheta=theta[1]-theta[0]

#creating the x, y coordinates of the first ring
x0,y0=(radius * np.cos(theta)), (radius * np.sin(theta))
#creating the x, y coordinates of the second ring
x1,y1=(radius * np.cos(theta+dtheta/2)) , (radius * np.sin(theta+dtheta/2))
#above first ring and second ring will come alternatively to form a tube. 
#plt.plot(x0,y0)
#plt.show()
#plt.plot(x1,y1)
#plt.show()
#now generating the z-coordinate of the first ring, second ring, third ring, etc.
cons0=np.ones(x0.shape)*0
cons1=np.ones(x1.shape)*2
cons2=np.ones(x0.shape)*4
cons3=np.ones(x1.shape)*6
cons4=np.ones(x0.shape)*8
cons5=np.ones(x1.shape)*10
cons6=np.ones(x0.shape)*12
cons7=np.ones(x1.shape)*14
cons8=np.ones(x0.shape)*16
cons9=np.ones(x1.shape)*18

###Now saving the x, y, z coordinates in csv files.

np.savetxt('cooRing00.csv',np.c_[x0,y0,cons0],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing01.csv',np.c_[x1,y1,cons1],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing02.csv',np.c_[x0,y0,cons2],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing03.csv',np.c_[x1,y1,cons3],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing04.csv',np.c_[x0,y0,cons4],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing05.csv',np.c_[x1,y1,cons5],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing06.csv',np.c_[x0,y0,cons6],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing07.csv',np.c_[x1,y1,cons7],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing08.csv',np.c_[x0,y0,cons8],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')
np.savetxt('cooRing09.csv',np.c_[x1,y1,cons9],delimiter=' ',fmt='%10f')

###Now, I have the x, y, z coordinates in many files (based on the length of the tube I want.
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: Okay @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

For the generation of your z-coordinate you can write something like:

```
def generate_z_coordinate(n, x0, x1):
    """Generate the z-coordinate for the n first ring.
       :param n: the number of ring
       :param x0: x0 coordinate
       :param x1: x1 coordinate
       :return: A list of the z-coordinate for the n rings
    """
    tmp = 0
    rings = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x = x0
        else:
            x = x1
        rings.append(np.ones(x.shape) * tmp)
        tmp += 2
    return rings
```

I used `tmp` because I lack a better name, but there is probably a better way to name it.

And saving in the csv:

```
def save(filename, rings, x0, y0, x1, y1):
    """Save rings coordinate into filename
       :param filename: Name of the file to save data in
       :param rings: list of z-coordinate for the rings
       :param x0: x0 coordinate
       :param y0: y0 coordinate
       :param x1: x1 coordinate
       :param y1: y1 coordinate
    """
    for i, elt in enumerate(rings):
        name = filename + str(i) + '.csv'
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x = x0
            y = y0
            z = rings[i]
        else:
            x = x1
            y = y1
            z = rings[i]

        np.savetxt(name, np.c_[x, y, z], delimiter=' ', fmt='%10f')
```

I am not sure it is more readable than your version but it's more scalable. Depend on what you need.

Also try to be consistant in your code and follow Python style guide(see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

- write `bLength = 1.6` instead of `bLength=1.6`
- `theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, numPoints, endpoint=False)`

You can use [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) or [black](https://github.com/ambv/black) or [PyLint](https://www.pylint.org/) to lint your code

Comment: I fixed the functions, is it working for you know?

Comment: I fixed the generation of the filename try it again. Your filename was `cooRing00.csv` etc my function is more like `cooRing0.csv` (without the trailing 0 before the number, maybe that trigger the error? I cant find if savetext need the file to already exist

Comment: cooxyz.csv need to be a string, 'cooxyz.csv' and the function add csv automatically, try save("cooxyz", rings, x0, y0, x1, y1)

Comment: I added the change name = filename + str(i) + '.csv'. Still I get following error: save(cooxyz, rings, x0, y0, x1, y1)
NameError: name 'cooxyz' is not defined